# TFS copy files step

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2018 and with a step for copying files where the following files and folders should be copied. However the obj folder is always copied as well. How can I prevent the obj folder to be copied?

```
> *.aspx
> *.ico
> *.js
> *.json
> *.config
> **/app/**/*.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I had specified default msbuild arguments in the step. Removing them solved my problem